# How to replace 0 with an empty string in PHP

Tags: php

I'm building a report in PHP, and am really new to this language.

I read the documentation on preg_replace, but it's not working exactly as I expect.

Here's my code:

```
    $pattern = 0;
    $replacement = ' ';

    $report_output.= '
        <td>'.preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, round($row[$win_count])).'</td>
    ';
```

Instead of replacing a result of 0 with an empty string, it replaces all results with an empty string. The round works great like this:

```
    <td>'.round($row[$win_count]).'</td>
```

It's just when I put the preg_replace around it, it says 'phooey, I shall replace everything'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `str_replace` instead, you don't need regex in your case. You just want to replace all the occurence of the given string. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php

Comment: `0` is not the same as `'0'`

Comment: where are those delimiters at? try this `'/^0$/'` as your pattern. `^` is start `$` is end so match only one `0`

Comment: I am new and didn't understand delimiters - I had tried delimiters previously but didn't have it right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$pattern = '/^0$/';
$replacement = ' ';

$report_output.= '
    <td>'.preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, round($row[$win_count])).'</td>
';
```

- The `^` means match start of string
- The `0` is match one 0
- The `$` means match end of string

So it will only match `'0'` one zero start to finish and not something like this `hell0` the end 0 wont be matched because the `l` is not the start of the string.

Your question is confusing if you want any 0 anywhere then use this instead

```
$pattern = '/0/';
```

With delimiters.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I appreciate your guidance and apologize for being confusing. I edited my original question so hopefully it's more clear for others.

Comment: You know round has a second parameter? for the precision which is the number of decimals http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: I don't think I endorse regex for this very simple task.

Comment: @mickmackusa - I would agree with this.  However I was just fixing the existing code as It was a more general error with missing the delimiters in the regex, which may help the OP more with further Regex attempts. then simply showing them how to replace the 0.  In general showing 0's that are not number fields would probably be a formatting error in the data which should be null or empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple shorthand ternary.

Generally: `$variable ?: ''`

If it is a false value, then the fallback empty string will be used.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F49cL))

```
printf(
    '"%s" vs "%s"',
    round($row[$win_count]),
    round($row[$win_count]) ?: ''
);
```

Output:

```
"0" vs ""
```